# JavaScript: I have a date, I need to know the date of the Wednesday of that week

Tags: javascript, date

In our ITSM tool we have an email that goes out with our CAB meeting info. Our Change request has a due_date that looks like 2013-09-31 08:00:00.

We have a CAB meeting every Wednesday so we need to calculate the Wednesday of the week this due_date belongs in. Whether the Wednesday is before, after, or the same day as due_date it doesn't matter. All changes need to go to CAB the Wednesday of the week they are due.

Anyone have ANY idea how this can be done?

Comment: getDay() is an integer corresponding to the day of the week: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date(); // pass the real date here
var day = d.getDay(); // day of the week
var date = d.getDate(); // day of the month
var noOfWeeksAhead = 1;
d.setDate(date + 3 + 7 * noOfWeeksAhead - day); // 3 = wednesday, 7 for next week
```

This gives me the next Wednesday, 18th December. If you need the Wednesday of that week, set `noOfWeeksAhead` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var wed = function(d) {
    return new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + 3 - d.getDay());
}
```

This assumes that Sunday is considered the first day of the week in your area.  If Sunday is the last day, it would take some tweaking.